# Xcode GPX file to Cllocation Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cllocation, gpx

i want to "simulate" GPS Coordinates, for that i want to go throw an array with latitude and longitude in a loop.

Now i have a gpx file and want to convert it to an cllocation array to use it in the loop.

Is there a way to convert a gpx file to a cllocation array?

greets